# Number of Invertible Elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, inverse

How do you find the number of (and how to construct) invertible elements of the polynomial ring $F_2[X]/⟨X^n−1⟩$ for general $n$? I know the factorization of $X^n-1$ is useful but I'm not sure how to apply this here.

Comment: Hint: In a direct product of rings $R_1\times\cdots\times R_k$, the invertible elements are precisely those for which each $j$th coordinate is invertible in $R_j$. Can you write $F_2[X]/⟨X^n−1⟩$ as a direct product of simpler rings?

Comment: Thanks! You can just split the direct product of rings for each factor and find the product of the number of invertible elements in each ring.